# Non-static method of a different class cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static-methods

I have a class named `AttachmentsBean` which has a method named `showUploadDialog()`. In another class named `UploadBean`, when I execute the following code :

```
if(count=0)
{
   return AttachmentsBean.showUploadDialog();
}
```

I get the error:

> "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

`AttachmentsBean.showUploadDialog()` is appropriate only if `showUploadDialog` is declared with the `static` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of showUploadDialog() should be like this

```
public static <return type> showUploadDialog() {
 //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AttachmentsBean.showUploadDialog() only if showUploadDialog declared as static:

```
public static ... showUploadDialog() {
  ...
}
```

if you need to call no-static method, you need at first create AttachmentsBean object, for example:

```
if(count=0)
{
   return new AttachmentsBean().showUploadDialog();
}
```